# How can I add Java in Joomla

Tags: java, joomla

When I attempt to add java code, it gets broken when Joomla makes the output to the front page viewing.
Joomla is adding a slash ( / ) prior to the http and this stops it from working.

I have tried what I can/know. Turn off WYSIWYG editor, paste publish etc.
Installed components that can paste in code... etc.

```
src=''http' + (location.protocol===
```

Turns into:

```
src=''/http' + (location.protocol===
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use *Javascript* rather than *Java* - they're completely different languages. I suggest you edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Check this out https://www.balbooa.com/knowledgebase/32-documentation-faq-joomla/180-how-to-stop-cleaning-html-and-scripts-code-in-joomla

Comment: @Nilsy If you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.